# Unity Addressables System: Can I make a script addressable and load/use at runtime (and how)?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, assets, assetbundle

I try to make an addressable scene, but the scripts of it must be at the project's directory in order to run in the addressable scene (when it is loaded).
The thing is that I need to build them into the addressable and load/use them at runtime.

I tried drag and drop the scripts in the addressable, like I use to do with my prefabs but it won't work.

Comment: Scripts don't work that way. You have to have them in the main project in order for them to be compiled.

Comment: Did you get any workaround for this?